# Excel hyperlink not working "cannot open the specified file"

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have a python app and I'm using xlwings to write to an Excel file. I am trying to create a link to another file. For now, I am trying to link to an Excel file. I am using the code:

```
ws.range(15, 8).value = '=HYPERLINK("C:\\file.xlsx")'
```

This creates a link but when I click the link I get the error "cannot open the specified file". The cell value is `=HYPERLINK("C:\file.xlsx")`. If I create a link to the same file using the "Insert Link" button in Excel it works and both cells show the same file path. Also I will need to create a link to a non-excel file that needs to be opened with a different program. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`add_hyperlink` method](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.add_hyperlink).

Example:

```py
ws.range(15, 8).add_hyperlink("C:\\file.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a protocol - specifically, `file`.

Changing your link to `file:///C:/file.xlxs` would likely solve your problem.  Non excel files would be opened with the default program for that file type (e.g. .txt would open notepad)

Comment: I did try this but I get the same error, with cell value =HYPERLINK("file:///C:\file.xlxs")

Comment: That is the incorrect slash for a Windows directory.  Windows uses `/`, not `\`.  Use `file:///C:/file.xlxs` as I described.

Comment: I have tried both and get the same error, but the link that does work that I created using the insert link button shows the path as file:///C:\file.xlxs